# Utilize remote PC to Boost UE4 Editor Performance

Tags: shaders, rendering, unreal-4, pc

As the title suggests, I would like to know **how I can take advantage of a desktop PC at my workplace to help boost the performance of the editor on my laptop at home.**

General editor actions such as shader compilation, light building, and terrain generation require large amounts of CPU power and RAM, both of which are much better suited for a desktop PC. **It would be great if there is a service that can allow me to offload the tasks from my laptop to the remote PC.** Unfortunately, directly remoting into that PC does not work for my case.

I am aware of a system known as UnrealSwarm, but have had difficulty finding recent documentation and substantial resources showing it can effectively run jobs other than lightmass rendering.

Please let me know how I can solve my problem!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swarm is only for building lights since it is often a long, CPU intensive process so Swarm "borrows" spare CPU cycles from other machines it's installed on to speed up the process.

I don't know of any option for general editor work you can use to achieve what you're trying to do besides installing the editor directly onto your work computer and using a remote desktop connection.

Comment: I see. That's a real bummer. Thanks for the help! Hopefully someone at Epic comes up with something to help